# An Unexpected I/O exception with AsyncHttpClient while performing SSL requests

Tags: java, scala, playframework, netty

My company works with Play framework and Scala as our backend server. Lately we've been having problems with the server. While making a secured (SSL) request to a remote API, we're getting the exception below.
Seems to be a problem regarding to the SSL, but I'm not sure. 
We had a similar problem a month ago, and setting the flag:

-J-XX:-UseAESIntrinsics -DXX:-UseAESIntrinsics

seemed to help. Now the problem is back.

Some more information:
- Play 2.5.9
- Scala 2.11.8
- Server OS: Centos 6.8
- JVM 1.8.0_25

The Exception:

- AsyncHttpClient-2-4 - 2016-12-21 03:59:17,434 - [debug] - from org.asynchttpclient.netty.handler.HttpHandler - Unexpected I/O exception on channel [id: 0x9ad15e31, L:/[IP_ADDRESS:PORT - R:SERVER/IP_ADDRESS:443]
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.GCTR.reset(GCTR.java:125)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.GCTR.doFinal(GCTR.java:116)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.doLastBlock(GaloisCounterMode.java:343)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:511)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1023)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:960)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:479)
  at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:830)
  at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2416)
  at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:535)
  at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(EngineInputRecord.java:200)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:968)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:901)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:775)
  at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1094)
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:966)
  at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:900)
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
  at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be and how can we fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Shlomi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should upgrade your java version. 1.8.0_25 is very old and from the stacktrace it looks like a JDK bug. Upgrade to latest Java 8 version and see if it still happens ( I suspect the answer is no ;))